# Using an event subscriber to "override" event caller's method

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, return, break

Pardon the phrasing, I am not too experienced with some of these concepts just yet. But is there a way (with C#) to use a "delegate" called through an event, which actually overrides the method from where the event was called?

I think I have a solution for this when there is only one subscriber to an event. But not if I want to override when a specific subscriber's method is called.

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this question is a bit all over the place

//Example pseudocode might explain question better

```
class Broadcaster{
  public delegate void myDelegate();
   public event myDelegate myEvent;     


    void foo(){
        if(myEvent != null){
            myEvent();

            **Here is the issue**
            //How can I return here, not for every subscriber
            //but only if a subscriber wants to?
            return;
        }

       //Do Something if a subscriber has not already returned
    }    
}


class Listener(){

    void Start(){
        FindObjectOfType<Broadcaster>().myEvent += OnBroadcasterEvent();

    }

    public void OnBroadcasterEvent(){
        //Do something



        **Here is the issue**
        //Return, or, break from parent method (i.e. where event was called from)
    } 

}
```

Comment: Sorry, just to gain some more understanding... Are you looking to break out of a loop/function, upon an event being risen?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like delegates are not the answer you are looking for, as they may be executed in an unknown order.

The way ASP.NET handles it's pipeline may be a better method.  Basically there is a call chain and each part of the chain calls the next one in the chain until one of them just returns.

Each 'handler' is constructed with the 'next' handler in the chain to call and then you 'call' the head of the chain.

```
 public class MyHandler
 {
     private Func<MyRequest, MyResult> _next;
     public MyHandler(Func<MyRequest,MyResult> next) => _next = next;

     public MyResult Handle(MyRequest request)
     {
         if(IWantToShortCircuit)
         {
              return request;
         }

         return _next(request);
     }
 }
```

So you can end up with chains like this:

```
  I1       I1
   |        ^
   v        |
  I2       O2
   |        ^
   v        |
  I3 --->  O3
```

Or you can short-circuit

```
  I1       I1
   |        ^
   v        |
  I2  ---> O2


  I3       O3
```

In the 2nd example, I2 has decided to short circuit, and I3 has not been called.